# How to prevent a cursed artifact's guard from revealing its true nature?

Tags: science-based, memory

I have cursed artifacts that can work together to kill people. It's logical for these cursed artifacts to have some kind of an anti-meme measure, so as to prevent their true nature from being revealed, despite their guard's, Fafnir's, best attempts

The focus isn't on the dragon here, but how utterly perfect the censoring mechanism of the artifacts is, being able to handle any situation at hand. From trying to just tell people, to carving "Baby Stand" in your hands, it handles everything, even the anomalies it creates. It can't, however, control minds, and is fairly localized.

Magical artifacts are a sophisticated, completely scientific, technology that have a limited battery-capacity, measured in charges. Charges  can be recovered by placing the items on one of the abundant tesla-lines (the cooler version of a ley-line) that wirelessly recharge them over time.

**I'm looking for (preferably one) simple, and plausible, way for these artifacts to be able to effectively vanish any information about them. What could that be?**

Comment: It bummed me out when I attached snips of stories and it got me downvotes.  Some folks here are all business.  I must say I was surprised when your story did not involve the artifacts altering reality as per your question.   Consider making a (free!) account on fictionpress.com and you can post your stories and then a link to the one you think is relevant.

Comment: @Willk Okay, but I have some things to take care of first.

Comment: Think about saving your story as a word file.  If people downvote you because they don't think there should be stories here, they will not be back to retract the downvote and that is irksome.

Comment: @Willk I think I can put Universe Factory to use this time. brb

Answer (score 2):

**The artifacts have an alias.**

There is history out in the world about an artifact that looks like a stone fist the size of a melon, that will punch you in the junk if you don't say the magic words.  It has a bunch of other properties too.  There are stories out there about the Fist.  How can the Fist evade this?

The Fist stops looking like a Fist.  It looks like a sun hat with silk flowers.  It does not punch people in the junk.

People know stories about the Stone Fist but are not aware this cute sun hat is the same thing.   If it turns back into a Fist people might remember the stories, but as long as it keeps up its sun hat appearances no-one would put things together.

Answer (score 1):

**Alter the Information**

If it can't control minds to get at the information within it, the artifact does the next best thing - it targets the information when it gets passed down. Information is generally passed down either verbally or visually, and when either one happens, the artifact intercepts it and either swaps in dummy information (every time you try saying the artifact's name, you end up saying 'a loaf of bread') or just white noises it.